# Duplicating Magento (sub)categories with php?

Tags: php, magento, categories

I'm working on a car part store with Magento and there needs to be +20 sub categories(lights, brakes etc) under each brand subcategories(Alfa, Volvo etc) under rootcategories "Used" and "New". That's hell of a work do manually, adding them one by one and I don't want to buy 60-80$ an extension for a school work like this.

I've already done some research on google but nothing really seems to fit for this case, as I'm a noobie with Magento and php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doing this manually will be a pain. Here's what I recommend. There's a great tool for mass importing/exporting products, attributes, or categories. This tool is called Magmi.

What I recommend you do is create a script or find a way to automate the creation of a .csv that follows Magmi's guidelines at the link below.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer

Here's their main wiki: http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Importing these with a csv is the best option I can come up with. It's relatively simple to create Python code that will automatically create entries into the csv for you. It WILL require a little bit of work though. Just up to you to decide which amount of work is more worth it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll will check this out :)

Comment: Let me know if it helps at all!